# プロフィール設定画面のエラーメッセージが翻訳されていません

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

Sorry, I don't speak Japanese, but there is no localization for the error on Profile Settings Page.
(翻訳：すいません、日本語は喋れないのですが、プロフィール設定画面のエラーがローカライゼーションされていないことに気づきました。)

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Thanks for reporting! It seems that this string is already translated before, but isn't synchronized with the site. I asked about this to the translation manager of this site [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46698152#46698152).　／　この文字列は既に翻訳されているようですが、サイトに反映されていないようです。チャットで aki さんに聞いてみています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スペイン語版サイトでも同じようなバグが見つかり修正されました。次のビルドで適用される予定です。